# Scaffold-DbContext does not add Table attribute even when DataAnnotations param is supplied

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, asp.net-core-webapi

I am scaffolding my db in a `dotnet core EF6` project, in order to generate my models using `Scaffold-DbContext` command *(reverse engineering)*. I'm trying to avoid manual `EntityTypeConfiguration`, hence supplied `DataAnnotations` parameter as well. Like:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=localhostxx;...;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -Context "MyDbContext" -f -Project Processor.Common -DataAnnotations
```

This decorates the generated models with expected attribures *(Required, Length, etc.)*. But it doesn't add `[Table("TableName")]` attribute above the generated class. Therefore, I still have to provide manual configuration which at least defines mapping. For instance:

```
//for Student table, I created DbSet prop in dbcontext class as:
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

//configuration for Students DbSet
public class StudentConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentConfiguration ()
        : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public StudentConfiguration (string schema)
    {
        ToTable("Student", schema);
    }
}

//then OnModelCreating
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentConfiguration());
```

If I don't define this, it throws exception on db call, saying something like, *couldn't find table dbo.Student*. Is there anyway that generated entity classes have `Table` by default? so that I don't have to manually configure each new table.